# How react state works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I'm working with controlled form and have **`handleChange`** function, that get input value and save it in state like **`state.mainField.firstInput`**.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    // the input value was 2, then I enter 3
    console.log(this.state.mainField.firstInput); // expect 2
    console.log(this.state); // expect { mainField: { firstInput: 3 } }
    /*
     ...
    */
    this.setState({ mainField: newData });
}
 /*
  ...
 */
<form>
  <input value={this.state.mainField.firstInput} onChange={this.handleChange} />
</form>
```

When I'm trying print **`state.mainField.firstInput`** to the console on the top of the **`handleChange`** function I got different result with **`state`**    in the same field. Exact **`firstInput`** property was current state value and property in object **`this.state`** was like after **`setState`** functions. Why this same values are different?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to note here

1. `setState` is `asynchronous` and hence it won't reflect the change immediately
2. Secondly when you log an object with `console.log()`, it is evaluated after you expand it and hence by that time the value is updated. Hence you see the difference between

```js
console.log(this.state.mainField.firstInput); // expect 2
console.log(this.state); // expect { mainField: { firstInput: 3 } }
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is an synchronous and single-threaded language.
So it runs line-by-line

You are console-logging before your state changes so It'll obviously give 2.
Even if you console.log after setting the state then also you may not get the expected result because the set state takes time to execute.

// This may or may not work

```
    handleChange = (e) => {
    // the input value was 2, then I enter 3
    console.log(this.state.mainField.firstInput); // expect 2        

    this.setState({ mainField: newData });
    console.log(this.state); // expect { mainField: { firstInput: 3 } }
}
```

But this will surely work

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
        // the input value was 2, then I enter 3
        console.log(this.state.mainField.firstInput); // expect 2        

        this.setState({ mainField: newData },()=>{
console.log(this.state); // expect { mainField: { firstInput: 3 } }
    });

    }
```

Comment: this two console.log print different values before setState